# How to return the child process once the stdout stops emitting things

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I have to create a tomcat server using node, I know, it's a bit weird but it's for learning purposes. So, basically, I have function that uses `shelljs` to spawn the server:

```
function spawnTomCat() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = shell.exec('create server', {
      async: true
    })

    child.stdout.on('data', data => {
      // this is called several times, and I want to resolve the promise in the last
      // call.
      if (lastCall()) {
        resolve(child)
      }
    })

    child.stderr.once('data', reject)
  })
}
```

Basically, because it's a server, the `child.on('close')` won't ever be called, and if I call the `resolve` function on the first execution of the `child.stdout.on('data')` callback, the server will be starting. I could paste the things that I've tried, but none of them really worked, but I tried to:

- use the exec - callback won't ever be fired
- use sync - will block and further code won't be executed

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  What exact event do you want to correspond to when the promise is resolved, when the server is up and running?  Unless the server is sending a specific piece of data on `stdout` when it's up and running and ready for requests, there's no way for you to guess that from reading `stdout`.  You could poll the new server with simple requests and when you get an appropriate response, you know it's up and running and working.

Comment: You could use timers to see when there's been no more data on stdout for some period of time, but that is just a guess.  The server could be sitting at a prompt waiting for a database access password to be entered by a sysadmin or it could be taking unusually long to start this time because of some resource contention with something that it needs in order to start.

Comment: @jfriend00 exactly, I want to resolve a soon as the server is fully up and running. I thought about using a timer, but that seems a bad workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you want to resolve when the server is up and running.  There are really only two ways I can think of to know that.

**1. Have the server tell you.**  The server writes some known data to stdout (or some other communication channel) when the server thinks that it's up and running and ready for requests so you can monitor that channel and known when it's good to go.

**2. You poll the server.**  You send test requests to find out when it's responding properly to some simple request.

A timer watching for a pause in stdout data is a hack and is subject to all sorts of opportunities to be wrong.

Comment: Hm, I haven't thought about the **1.** and I really like it. I could simply test if the string contains "server fully initialized".